# Mysql IN() not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a checkbox form which passes an array of id values. I then implode the array like this:

```
$ship = $_POST['result'];
$array=implode(",", $ship);
$shipping=ship_update($array);
```

The Mysql query function looks like this:

```
function ship_update($array){
    global $MEMS;
    echo $array;
    $query="SELECT * FROM Inventory
        WHERE MEMS_ID IN ('$array')
            ORDER BY WAFER ASC, RC ASC";
    $shipping=$MEMS -> exec($query);
    return $shipping;
}
```

When I run this code, $shipping returns an empty query. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should echo your query to see what's wrong yourself. You're missing the quotes in your values when you explode like this.

Comment: What does `$query` turn out to be? Also, remember to sanitize any user-entered fields before putting them into a query.

Answer (score 2):

This should be

```
$array = "'" . implode("','", $ship) . "'";
```

And in your query,

```
$query="SELECT * FROM Inventory
        WHERE MEMS_ID IN ($array)    // remove the single quotes to
        ORDER BY WAFER ASC, RC ASC"; // avoid syntax error
```

*warning, this is still vulnerable with sql injection*.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also, $shipping=$MEMS -> exec($query) is suppose to be $shipping=$MEMS -> query($query). That was the second mistake. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Try your query without `'` single quotes

```
SELECT * FROM Inventory
        WHERE MEMS_ID IN ($array)
            ORDER BY WAFER ASC, RC ASC
```

Comment: this is the best answer provided the ids are numbers only

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any single quotes in the middle of your array. Change

```
$array=implode(",", $ship);
```

to

```
$array=implode("','", $ship);
```